# How to set a field required in joomla 2.5?

Tags: required, joomla2.5

I have created a component. In this component I have created the form fields  using xml file.
In xml file I set the attribute `required='required'` of a text field and that field become a required field automatically.

But Now I have a component which has created the form in a php file using html input tags. And now I want to make a textfield required in that form so how will I do this? As in the input tag I can't enter the `required='required'` attribute.

So what should I do with this so that the textbox becomes a required field and without entering some text in that field it should not be submitted.

Comment: Any one who can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following website to add validation for the php form fields.

http://buildinternet.com/2008/12/how-to-validate-a-form-complete-with-error-messages-using-php-part-1/

http://phpmaster.com/form-validation-with-php/